# Confirm leaving the store when there are products in cart with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to show to users a popup with notification like "You have products in your cart. Do you really want to leave?" when they are trying to leave a store with product in cart.

My code:

```
if ($( ".blockcart" ).hasClass( "active" )) {
  console.log("Cart isn't empty");

  $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
  });

} else {
  console.log("Cart empty.");
}
```

The thing is, the popup shows after every page quit request - even if they want to just go to another store page. I would like to show it only when they close the browser window or completely leave store "domain" or something like this. Is there a posibility to make it work as it should?

Comment: Please search before posting, there are dozens of questions about this already, many with useful answers. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a way for JavaScript to know whether you’re going to another store page or leaving entirely. That is, to know where you’re going.

As far as I am aware, JavaScript has no way of knowing where you’re going next.

In the most extreme case, you might just click on a bookmark or type in a new URL. If JavaScript was able to determine where you’re going with that, then it could also be used to spy on you, which is something that browsers try very hard not to allow.

Short answer is: I don’t think you can.